# Fetch Requests in different pages with React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, fetch-api

I'm building a website using React Hooks and I've got two different pages (Workshops.js and Shows.js) fetching data from the same API, just with different parameters (?type=0 and ?type=1).
Once the data is fetched I'm mapping the results (It would be nice to have a reusable component there..see the comments in the code below). When the user click either on a show or a workshop he will be redirected to the same page.

Now singularly the code works.
Is there a more elegant way to avoid repeating the same code? ...something like Services in Angular?

Thank you!

Here is Workshop.js.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import api from '../../maps/Api' 

const Workshops = () => {
    const [ workshops, setWorkshop ] = useState([])
    const [ isLoading, setIsLoading ] = useState(false)
    const [ error, setError ] = useState(null)
    const GET_URL = api.get.workshops /* http://someapi/workshops?type=0 */

    useEffect(() => {
        setIsLoading(true)
        fetch(GET_URL, {headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
        }})
        .then(res => {
            return (res.ok) ?  res.json() : new Error("Mistake!")
        })
        .then(workshops => {
            if(workshops.upcoming) {
                setWorkshop(workshops.upcoming);
            }
            setIsLoading(false);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            setError(error)
        })
    }, [GET_URL])

    if ( error ){ return <p>{ error.message }</p> }
    if ( isLoading ){
        return <p>Loading workshops...</p>
    }

    return(

        <main>
            <div className='content'>
                <div className='contentCol'>
                    <ul id='workshopBox'>
                    {
                        workshops.map( (workshop, i) => (
                            <li> // FROM HERE...
                                <div
                                    className='workshop-active'>
                                    <h2>{ workshop.title }</h2>
                                    <p>{ workshop.description }</p>
                                    <p>{ workshop.place }</p>
                                    <p>{ (new Date(workshop.date).toLocaleDateString("it-IT", {
                                            weekday: 'long',
                                            year: 'numeric',
                                            month: 'long',
                                            day: 'numeric'
                                          }))}</p>
                                    <p>{ (new Date(workshop.date).toLocaleTimeString("it-IT", {
                                            hour: '2-digit',
                                            minute: '2-digit',
                                            hour12: true
                                          }))}</p>
                                    <p> Full price { workshop.price_full + ', 00'} &euro; </p>
                                    <p> Early bird price { workshop.price_earlybirds + ', 00'} &euro; </p>
                                    <p>
                                    <Link to={`/workshops/${ workshop.id}`}>
                                        <button>Details</button>
                                    </Link>
                                    </p>
                                    <br/>
                                </div>
                            </li> //..to HERE I WOULD LIKE TO USE A REUSABLE COMPONENT
                            ))
                    }
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
        )
    }

export default Workshops
```

and here's Shows.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
//import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import api from '../maps/Api'

const Spettacoli = () => {
    const [ shows, setShows ] = useState([])
    const [ isLoading, setIsLoading ] = useState(false)
    const [ error, setError ] = useState(null)
    const GET_URL = api.get.shows /* http://someapi/workshops?type=1 */

    useEffect(() => {
        setIsLoading(true)
        fetch(GET_URL, {headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
        }})
        .then(res => {
            return (res.ok) ?  res.json() : new Error("Mistake!")
        })
        .then(shows => {
            setShows(shows)
            setIsLoading(false)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            setError(error)
        })
    }, [GET_URL])


    return(
        <main>
            <div className='content'>
                <div className='contentCol'>
                    /* SAME INTERFACE AS WORKSHOP */

                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
        )
}

export default Shows
```

Comment: do shows have exactly the same interface as the workshops?

Comment: Yes! Just edited my post.

Comment: Just pass the type as props to your component and set your api with the props value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you may create your [custom hook](https://en.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html):

```
function useMyDataFetch(GET_URL) {
    const [ data, setData ] = useState([])
    const [ isLoading, setIsLoading ] = useState(true)
    const [ error, setError ] = useState(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        let hasBeenAborted = false; // added
        setIsLoading(true)
        fetch(GET_URL, {headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
        }})
        .then(res => {
            return (res.ok) ?  res.json() : new Error("Mistake!")
        })
        .then(data => {
            if (hasBeenAborted) return; // added
            if(data.upcoming) {
                setData(data.upcoming);
            }
            setIsLoading(false);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            if (hasBeenAborted) return; // added
            setIsLoading(false); // added
            setError(error)
        });
        return () => { hasBeenAborted = true; } // added
    }, [GET_URL]);

    return { data, error, isLoading };
}
```

and use that in your components.

Notice lines I've marked with `// added`.
`hasBeenAborted` allows us react in case `GET_URL` has been updated for any reason for the same component. [Cleanup in `useEffect`](https://en.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup) is really important so we avoid race conditions.

Instead of `hasBeenAborted` flag we could use [`AbortController`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController/abort) but with that we would still fall into `catch` branch and need additional `if` to distinguish if request has been cancelled or actually failed. So just matter of taste to me.

As for your components they will use hook like that:

```
const Workshops = () => {
    const {isLoading, error, data: workshops} = useMyDataFetch(api.get.workshops);

    if ( error ){ return <p>{ error.message }</p> }
    if ( isLoading ){
        return <p>Loading workshops...</p>
    }

    return(
      // the same here
    );

}

export default Workshops
```

Comment: Everything works, thank you a lot! Is there a way to isolate in one shared component what's inside the return statement in Workshops and Shows? Since the code is the same... I tried with Context but it works only with one out of two.

Comment: @MarcoMazzai do you mean `JSX` part? you may do that just single component that takes a prop with either `api.get.workshops` or `api.get.shows` as a value.

Comment: Or maybe it'd rather make responsibility unclear. Probably you may just take everything inside `.map()` and extract that into something like `<Card />` keeping loading data logic still duplicated across `Workshops` and `Shows`

Comment: Yes, I mean the JSX part. I tried to use the props way but I had no luck so far.